How do I write the value "hex(4):ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00" to the Windows registry using C#?
If I export a registry key from the registry, in the new created .reg file I see this key and its value.
"ThisIsATest"=hex(4):ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00

How do I write such a value to the Windows registry using C#?
I send a
byte[] hexValue = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

Exporting the key, the value is now
"ThisIsATest"=hex:ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00

which is not what I wanted.
Testing the software using this key, it says the read value is not correct.
Using regedit, when the value is hex(4), I see a TYPE: REG_DWORD and (DWORD values (32 bit) not valid) in the Data column.

When having hex, I see REG_BINARY and the value ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 in the Data Column.

Any idea?

Please provide a [mre], i.e. full code to reproduce your problem. Just because you have a byte[] does not tell us how you write that to the Registry.

do you provide a Key Type?

@Raildex: if he does, it won't allow the combination of byte[] and RegistryKind.Dword

Why would you want to use an incorrect type? If it's a DWORD then pass an int 0xFFFF0000

C# does not allow you to create this invalid combination of type and data. However, you can use native methods to achieve this by using P/Invoke.
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RegistryHex4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern uint RegSetValueEx(
            UIntPtr hKey,
            string lpValueName,
            int Reserved,
            RegistryValueKind dwType,
            IntPtr lpData,
            int cbData);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern uint RegOpenKeyEx(
            IntPtr hKey,
            string subKey,
            int ulOptions,
            int samDesired,
            out UIntPtr hkResult);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int RegCloseKey(UIntPtr hKey);

        private static readonly IntPtr HKEY_CURRENT_USER = new IntPtr(-2147483647);

        private bool SetCurrentUserValue(string path, string keyName, byte[] data)
        {
            UIntPtr registryKey = UIntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8);
            Marshal.Copy(pData, data, 0, data.Length);
            try
            {
                if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, 0, 0x20006, out registryKey) != 0)
                    return false;

                if (RegSetValueEx(registryKey, keyName, 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord, pData, 8) != 0)
                    return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (registryKey != UIntPtr.Zero)
                    RegCloseKey(registryKey);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pData);
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            byte[] data = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            Console.WriteLine(p.SetCurrentUserValue("test", "name", data));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


It works perfectly, this is exactly what I was asking. Thank you very much

The .NET API does not allow you to pass data of inconsistent types, but you can call the Windows API
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern int RegSetValueEx(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, string lpValueName,
                                         int Reserved, RegistryValueKind dwType,
                                         byte[] lpData, int cbData);

RegSetValueEx(yourSubKey.Handle, "ThisIsATest", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord,
              hexValue, hexValue.Length);

